# How to use setRowViewSelected of ListRowPresenter

Tags: android, adapter, android-viewholder, android-tv, listrowpresenter

I am using default project for Android TV. Following is the code for creating cards in my `BrowseFragment`:

```
private void loadRows() {
    List<Movie> list = MovieList.setupMovies();
    ListRowPresenter mListRowPresenter = new ListRowPresenter();
    mRowsAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(mListRowPresenter);

    mListRowPresenter.setRowViewSelected(/*HOW TO GET VIEWHOLDER HERE?*/, false);

    CardPresenter cardPresenter = new CardPresenter();

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS; i++) {
        if (i != 0) {
            Collections.shuffle(list);
        }
        ArrayObjectAdapter listRowAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(cardPresenter);
        for (int j = 0; j < NUM_COLS; j++) {
            listRowAdapter.add(list.get(j % 5));
        }
        HeaderItem header = new HeaderItem(i, MovieList.MOVIE_CATEGORY[i]);
        mRowsAdapter.add(new ListRow(header, listRowAdapter));
    }

    setAdapter(mRowsAdapter);
}
```

I am doing this as I don't want to make first card of row get selected when I launch app. It should only get selected after user press down button on Dpad. If I can't do it this way, what should I do to get mentioned behavior?

Comment: You could requestFocus on a different element on the screen - like the SearchOrb. Or customize the BackgroundManager to not always show the image on the background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `setRowViewSelected` by subclassing ListRowPresenter and overriding `initializeRowViewHolder(RowPresenter.ViewHolder holder)`

```
@Override
protected void initializeRowViewHolder(RowPresenter.ViewHolder holder) {
    super.initializeRowViewHolder(holder);

    setRowViewSelected(holder, false);
}
```

But I don't think you can unselect all items in `BrowseFragment` using this approach.

Try setting your `ItemViewSelectedListener` after your data is loaded instead of setting in `onActivityCreated` to have all items unselected on initial launch.

**Possible reason** why top left item of row will always get selected by default and you cannot have all unselected items on initial launch:

`BrowseFragment`'s `onItemSelected` method ([line 1372-1382](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v17/leanback/src/android/support/v17/leanback/app/BrowseFragment.java#1374))  on initial launch calls `mMainFragmentRowsAdapter.getSelectedPosition()`

```
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(Presenter.ViewHolder itemViewHolder, Object item,
            RowPresenter.ViewHolder rowViewHolder, Row row) {
        int position = mMainFragmentRowsAdapter.getSelectedPosition(); //<--
        if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "row selected position " + position);
        onRowSelected(position);
        if (mExternalOnItemViewSelectedListener != null) {  //<--
            mExternalOnItemViewSelectedListener.onItemSelected(itemViewHolder, item,
                    rowViewHolder, row);
        }
    }
```

where `getSelectedPosition()` always returns 0
([line 483-485](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v17/leanback/src/android/support/v17/leanback/app/BrowseFragment.java#483))

```
    public int getSelectedPosition() {
        return 0;
    }
```

It also calls `mExternalOnItemViewSelectedListener.onItemSelected` where `mExternalOnItemViewSelectedListener` is the ItemViewSelectedListener that you set in `MainFragment` of your app.

So  on initial launch, 0th item in 0th row gets selected as a default selected item but if you delay setting `mExternalOnItemViewSelectedListener` this call will not reach your item selected listener the first time.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this callback method .

```
   void onRowViewSelected (RowPresenter.ViewHolder vh, 
                    boolean selected)
```

Called when the given row view changes selection state. A subclass may override this to respond to selected state changes of a Row. A subclass may make visual changes to Row view but must not create animation on the Row view.

```
mListRowPresenter.setRowViewSelected(vh, false);
```

why you are deselecting initially ?  i didn't get your Question Clearly can you please explain what you want to do Exactly ??

Comment: Thing is that when we launch this app, top left item of row will get selected by default and its background image will be displayed. What I need to do is that I have to show different background image until user select any card item.